# Dijkstra Algorithm how to make it work directed

Tags: java, android, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am using the method below to implement the algorithm to find the shortest path.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DijkstraAlgorithm {

        private final List<Node> nodes;
        private final List<Edge> edges;
        private Set<Node> settledNodes;
        private Set<Node> unSettledNodes;
        private Map<Node, Node> predecessors;
        private Map<Node, Integer> distance;

        public DijkstraAlgorithm(Graph graph) {
            // create a copy of the array so that we can operate on this array
            this.nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(graph.getNodelIst());
            this.edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(graph.getEdgeList());
        }

        public void execute(Node source) {
            settledNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
            unSettledNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
            distance = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
            predecessors = new HashMap<Node, Node>();
            distance.put(source, 0);
            unSettledNodes.add(source);
            while (unSettledNodes.size() > 0) {
                Node node = getMinimum(unSettledNodes);
                settledNodes.add(node);
                unSettledNodes.remove(node);
                findMinimalDistances(node);
            }
        }

        private void findMinimalDistances(Node node) {
            List<Node> adjacentNodes = getNeighbors(node);
            for (Node target : adjacentNodes) {
                if (getShortestDistance(target) > getShortestDistance(node)
                        + getDistance(node, target)) {
                    distance.put(target, getShortestDistance(node)
                            + getDistance(node, target));
                    predecessors.put(target, node);
                    unSettledNodes.add(target);
                }
            }

        }

        private int getDistance(Node node, Node target) {
            for (Edge edge : edges) {
                if (edge.getSourceNode().equals(node)
                        && edge.getEndNode().equals(target)) {
                    return edge.getWeight();
                }
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Should not happen");
        }

        private List<Node> getNeighbors(Node node) {
            List<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
            for (Edge edge : edges) {
                if (edge.getSourceNode().equals(node)
                        && !isSettled(edge.getEndNode())) {
                    neighbors.add(edge.getEndNode());
                }
            }
            return neighbors;
        }

        private Node getMinimum(Set<Node> vertexes) {
            Node minimum = null;
            for (Node vertex : vertexes) {
                if (minimum == null) {
                    minimum = vertex;
                } else {
                    if (getShortestDistance(vertex) < getShortestDistance(minimum)) {
                        minimum = vertex;
                    }
                }
            }
            return minimum;
        }

        private boolean isSettled(Node vertex) {
            return settledNodes.contains(vertex);
        }

        private int getShortestDistance(Node destination) {
            Integer d = distance.get(destination);
            if (d == null) {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            } else {
                return d;
            }
        }

    /*
     * This method returns the path from the source to the selected target and
     * NULL if no path exists
     */
    public LinkedList<Node> getPath(Node target) {
        LinkedList<Node> path = new LinkedList<Node>();
        Node step = target;
        // check if a path exists
        if (predecessors.get(step) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        path.add(step);
        while (predecessors.get(step) != null) {
            step = predecessors.get(step);
            path.add(step);
        }
        // Put it into the correct order
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }


    }
```

This works fine, however i now wish to add a direction to my edges and run the same method directed, to return a directed PathList. i will pass a 11 for bidirectional, 01 for --> and 10 for <-- just for example. Does anyone have experience of this, i understand the concept but actually coding the method above to account for directionality is causing me an issue?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by directed?

Comment: @AliHassan Sorry, I mean i need to add a direction property to the edges, so they can be bi-directional or they can be only one direction. I.e if we were path planning and one edge was perhaps an escalator, so it can only be used in one direction. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you build your edges? Your algorithm seems to already have a concept with an edge having a source node and an end node.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö My edges have a property which is the Nodeids: [sourceID, DestinationID] so we do have an idea of direction, how do i then make the algorithm obey these rules? for instance i have an edge escalator node1--node2. When i have a bidirectional edge the direction is denoted by direction: 11. So are we thinking i need to make a copy of the bidirectional ones so i have node 3--node4 and node4--node3 and have both in my arraylist of edges. and on the directional ones i leave them and swap the source and destination at runtime when needed before i put them in the arraylist for the algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to keep your directional edges as is and create two edges if the connection is bi-directional.

Paraphrased
NodeAID, NodeBID, 01 gives `edges.add(new Edge(NodeAID, NodeBID))`

NodeAID, NodeBID, 10 gives `edges.add(new Edge(NodeBID, NodeAID))`

and NodeAID, NodeBID, 11 gives

```
edges.add(new Edge(NodeAID, NodeBID));    
edges.add(new Edge(NodeBID, NodeAID));
```

You could create an Edge interface which handles both unidirectional and bidirectional, but I think that would make it more complex one the edges start having different faiths in the different directions.